# WPF InputManager KeyDown not handled

Tags: wpf, routed-events

First of all I already have a working solution I just need some explanation on what is happening here.

I have the following code:

```
var e = new KeyEventArgs(Keyboard.PrimaryDevice, 
                         Keyboard.PrimaryDevice.ActiveSource, 
                         Environment.TickCount, 
                         Key.D1)
{
   RoutedEvent = Keyboard.KeyDownEvent
};
InputManager.Current.ProcessInput(e);
```

The purpose of this code is to add the value 1 to a currently focused textbox (= Keyboard.PrimaryDevice.ActiveSource).
But if I execute this code the text which is contained in the textbox wont change. But the routed "KeyDown" event is executed.

If I change the code from above to this, it is working:

```
var eventArgs = new TextCompositionEventArgs(Keyboard.PrimaryDevice,
                                             new TextComposition(InputManager.Current, 
                                             Keyboard.FocusedElement, "1"))
{
   RoutedEvent = ContentElement.TextInputEvent
};

InputManager.Current.ProcessInput(eventArgs);
```

Now my question is, why is it not working with the first example. In my understanding if the control receives a KeyDown Event the result should be that the text is changed? The interessting part is if I want to send special key events like Enter or Backspace I HAD to use code example 1 code example 2 wont work there.

This is a little bit tricky and I thought maybe someone can enlighten me?

Thank you in advance